# How can I configure diazo to not use jbot templates when requested from blacklisted hostnames?

Tags: plone, diazo

The following (zopeskel default) `diazotheme` includes a `jbot` directory `template_overrides`. In this directory there is an overriden version of `plone.app.layout.viewlets.footer.pt`.

When I configure `diazo` (`@@theming-controlpanel`) and blacklist a hostname, then the diazo theme is not shown (as expected) for the blacklisted hostname, but the `jbot` templates in `template_overrides` are still active.

How can I configure `diazo` to not use the `jbot` templates when requested from blacklisted hostnames?

The diazotheme was created with the command `zopeskel diazotheme namespace.package`

The relevant files are:

**namespace.package/namespace/package/interfaces.py**

```
from zope.interface import Interface
class ICustomTheme(Interface):
    """Marker interface that defines a Zope 3 browser layer.
    """
```

**namespace.package/namespace/package/profiles/default/browserlayer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layers>
    <layer name="namespace.package.customization.layer"
      interface="namespace.package.interfaces.ICustomTheme" />
</layers>
```

**namespace.package/namespace/package/configure.zcml**

```
  ...
  <browser:jbot
      directory="template_overrides"
      layer=".interfaces.ICustomTheme"
      />
  ...
```

**namespace.package/namespace/package/template_overrides/plone.app.layout.viewlets.footer.pt**

```
<div i18n:domain="plone" id="portal-footer">
    my footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layers are just interfaces that are applied to a request.

To accomplish what you're doing, it is possible to dynamically apply a layer to a request depending on the hostname by using request event.

Warning, this is all untested...

```
from ZPublisher.interfaces import IPubStart
from zope.component import adapter
from zope.interface import alsoProvides

@adapter(IPubAfterTraversal)
def applyLayer(event):
    req = event.request
    if req.URL == 'something':
        alsoProvides(req, IMyLayerThatHasJBOTCustomizations)
```